Google Auth on embedded user-agent
We use firebase auth in our js bluetooth web app and provide google login. It works fine on normal browsers but on bluefy (bluetooth browser for iOS) we get an "use secure browsers" error with the error code 403: disallowed_useragent.
The documentation states

A developer must not direct a Google OAuth 2.0 authorization request to an embedded user-agent under the developer's control. Embedded user-agents include, but are not limited to, software libraries that allow a developer to insert arbitrary scripts, alter the default routing of a request to the Google OAuth server, or access session cookies. All browsing environments must allow the user to verify the current connection to the Google OAuth server including the requested URI and connection security information.

Is there anything we can do about this issue ourself? Or can only the third party browser fix this issue?
The code snippet to trigger the auth flow:
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  console.log('signing in with google');
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    const result = await signInWithPopup(auth!, provider);
    const idToken = await result.user.getIdToken();
    
    await fetch("/api/login", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`,
      },
    });
      
    router.refresh();
};


Facing the same, did you ever find a solution?

@Ben we just dropped the google login support for that plattform, since as far as we understood google simply does not support certain browsers as a security feature.
